# What to consider when come to value of capacitor selection for C2

Tags: bjt, inverting-amplifier

For the circuit below, noticed the bypass capacitor C2 will pull down the amplified voltage if the reactance is too big but the node voltage R7, R8 and base of Q2 will increase on the other hand if using too small reactance, the voltage drop at node R7, R8 and Q2 will increase but the amplified signal will decrease.

[image: schematic]

So do we consider formulae below in obtaining to suitable capacitor?

on the 1st stage amplifier Q1, the gain will be

$$A_v=\frac{R_3||X_{c2}+(R_7||R_8||\beta_{Q2}(X_{c3}+r_{eQ2}'))}{450}$$

Then by voltage divider rule the node voltage R7,R8 and base of Q2 will be

$$V_{output}=A_v(Vin)(\frac{(R_7||R_8||\beta_{Q2}(X_{c3}+r_{eQ2})}{(R_7||R_8||\beta_{Q2}(X_{c3}+r_{eQ2})+X_{c2}})$$

Finding $$\frac{dV_{output}}{dC2}=0$$ to obtain the value of C?

Comment: The rule is R3 is the Ac load current must not exceed the DC current in R3, thus for large signals R8 must be greater than R3.  there are better ways to increase gain, lower output impedance and reduce THD. But you must define your I/O specs for gain , BW , THD and impedance.

Comment: Is this circuit a very distorted and very hot class-A audio amplifier?? A speaker performs poorly with the 0.75A of DC in it and the speaker and output transistor heat with a total of 9W all the time even when silent. The output power will be 1.3W maximum.

Comment: Is an assignment so actually I just applied what I learnt at the moment to construct my own circuit so the efficiency doesn't matter at the moment, I much keen to learn the working principle ie. the mathematics calculation part at the moment

Comment: You would never use this for audio design today because , too many caps, poor LF response, low gain, excess variation in Vbe which causes distortion of Ic as an AC multiplier. If you did, you would choose ReqC=T=10 to 100ms and scale all the R values to minimize C size , bypass Re on both stages but add 100 Ohms and get Av >60dB with less distortion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the left you have a signal source that is assumed to be "low impedance." (Actually, very very very low impedance.) This drives the circuit through \$C_1\$, which will have a frequency-dependent impedance.

> \$C_1\$ also develops a DC bias in operation that "matches" the
> signal source to the DC quiescent bias point of the 1st BJT stage's
> input. And it will be at some point important for you to see that
> fact. Though for now it isn't important.

In the following I'll assume a value of \$\beta=250\$ for \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$. It might be less or more. But that's the value I'm going with, below.

Your first stage is a CE voltage amplifier stage. The DC quiescent bias point for \$Q_1\$'s emitter can be computed to be about \$500\:\text{mV}\$ and therefore the emitter and collector currents are about \$1.1\:\text{mA}\$. This implies that \$r_e^{'}\$ will be about \$23.6\:\Omega\$. Odds are that there will also be a small Ohmic resistance at the emitter of about \$250\:\text{m}\Omega\$. So I'd round all this up to an AC emitter impedance (at its tip) of about \$24\:\Omega\$. So, discounting any attenuation due to \$C_1\$ and ignoring the load on \$Q_1\$'s collector (treat it as unloaded for now), I get \$A_{v_1}=\frac{4.8\:\text{k}\Omega}{450\:\Omega+24\:\Omega}\approx 10.13\$.

However, \$C_1\$ has about \$X_C\approx 160\:\Omega\$ at \$f=1\:\text{kHz}\$. The input impedance works out to about \$2.5\:\text{k}\Omega\$. So only about 94% of \$A_{v_1}\approx 10.13\$ remains, or about \$9.52\$.

The 2nd stage's DC bias point should be about the same as the first, except this one has its emitter resistor completely bypassed by \$C_3\$. \$C_3\$ has about \$X_C\approx 5.31\:\Omega\$ at \$f=1\:\text{kHz}\$. To this we can add \$C_3\$ in-quadrature impedance and get probably about \$25 \:\Omega\$ of AC impedance at the emitter of \$Q_2\$. So I get an input impedance of about \$1.8\:\text{k}\Omega\$ for the 2nd stage. (I'm mostly ignoring \$C_2\$ here.) This means about 27% of the 1st stage's output survives. So now the voltage gain is down to about \$2.6\$, before applying the 2nd stage's voltage gain.

The 2nd stage's voltage gain will be about \$190\$. So now we have a total unloaded output voltage gain of about \$A_v\approx 500\$. Those Darlington output transistors mean that it's not loaded much, so we can probably stick with that value as a rough estimate for the voltage gain of the system.

> However, while those emitter followers are great at pulling upward on
> the \$8\:\Omega\$ resistor, they are not so good at pulling downward.
> The \$8\:\Omega\$ has to do its own down-pulling.

Anyway, that's about all there is to it.

(LTspice reports almost a voltage gain very close to the above prediction.)

Comment: Thanks again for your crystal explanation.